# Brick, Round Corner and/or Plate, Round Corner with Curved Cutout fitting radius of 88293 - Brick, Round Corner 3 x 3 x 2 Dome Top

Tags: moc

I would like to build a rounded edge with [713 - Plate, Round Curved 4 x 8 Right](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=713#T=A) as base and the [88293 - Brick, Round Corner 3 x 3 x 2 Dome Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88293#T=A) on top.

Are there any rounded corner bricks or rounded corner plates (with curved cutout) that fits the radius of the 713 and 88293?

Or is there a construction technique that closely matches the radius?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there are no 3x3 macaroni bricks like you'd really like to be able to use here. There are [2x2](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3063b/brick-round-corner-2-x-2-macaroni-with-stud-notch/) and [4x4](https://rebrickable.com/parts/48092/brick-round-corner-4-x-4-macaroni-wide-with-3-studs/) macaroni bricks:

[image: 2x2 macaroni]

[image: 4x4 macaroni]

A [3x3 plate](https://rebrickable.com/parts/68568/plate-round-corner-3-x-3-with-2-x-2-round-cutout/) exists, but it actually has an outer radius of 2 and a short straight segment:

[image: 3x3 plate]

There are some parts that might be useful, depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish. There is a [3x3 round window](https://rebrickable.com/parts/73878/window-round-3-x-3-x-2/) element that could be useful if you are willing to add glass from floor to ceiling:

[image: 3x3 round window]

There is also a [half-circle panel](https://rebrickable.com/parts/87926/cylinder-half-3-x-6-x-6-with-1-x-2-cutout/) in this radius the could be useful:

[image: 3x6 round panel]

[3x3 wedge bricks](https://rebrickable.com/parts/2462/wedge-3-x-3-facet/) could be an option if you can compromise on having a truly round edge:

[image: 3x3 wedge facet]

There are also various ways you can get close to this angle using studs-not-on-top techniques. This can be especially useful if you are going for a brick or stone look. Here's one example:

[image: Rivendell step 239]

[image: Rivendell step 240]

That's not quite the 3x3 corner you are looking for, but the basic idea could be adapted to best suit your particular needs.

Here are some other possible ideas from existing sets. The towers in Kinddoms Joust:

[image: Kingdom's Joust]

The lighthouse in Lighthouse Point. This uses 2x2 macaroni bricks to build a not-quite-round 3x3 corner:

[image: Lighthouse Point]

The windows on the Pet Shop achieve a good estimation of this radius using 2x2 bricks and hinge plates:

[image: Pet Shop]

Here's the technique in detail:

[image: Pet Shop step 16]

Hopefully something in there is useful for inspiration. Feel free to ask for clarification via comments or ask other new questions about how to solve specific issues in your build.